# How can I remove all vowels from an inputted string

Tags: python, string, list

This doesn't really work

To explain what I did:
I set a vowel variable with a list
Then I used a for loop to iterate through the list and print the letters not in the list

[image]

Comment: Please never post code as images, simply copy/paste the code to your question and format it as code.

Comment: Try: `if letter.lower() not in vowels`

Answer (score 0):

as user @user56700 noted: You did, probably by mistake:

```
if not letter.lower in vowels:
```

instead:

```
if not letter.lower() in vowels:
```

first is method "itself", second is call of method.

P.S.
also, as user @user56700 noted, do not screenshot and paste code as image. Just paste and format as code, it is really simple, and shows that min of respect for others :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

vowel = input()

lst = re.sub("[aeiouAEIOU]","",vowel)

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
st=input("Enter Any String ")

vowel=['a','e','i','o','u']

#Create a List of Vowel

st=st.lower()

#Convert Vowel in Lower case

output=""

for i in st:     

    if i not in vowel:

    #Check Vowel if not then add to output

        output+=i

print(output)
```